# How do I retrieve Intent Extras within a Service started by an AlarmManager schedule?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    int idFunc = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SPREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("idFunc", 0);
    String SecKey = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SPREF_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("chave", null);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceEnviaClientes.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("SecKey", SecKey);
    bundle.putInt("idFunc", idFunc);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), 10*60000, pintent);
    initImageLoader(this);
}
```

I'm trying to pass extras provided by SharedPrefereces from an AlarmManager Intent and retrieve it within the Service, instead of access my SharedPreferences while the Service is running which I think demands more memory.

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this,"task perform in service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    mIdFunc = bundle.getInt("idFunc");
    mSecKey = bundle.getString("SecKey");
    ThreadJSONBuild td=new ThreadJSONBuild();
    td.start();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand cycle, idFunc: "+mIdFunc+" , SecKey: "+mSecKey);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

but I'm getting `null` on `mSecKey` and `0` on `idFunc`. I'm not sure if it's the best option, I'd put my SharedPreferences retrieves inside Service's `onCreate()` method, but not sure really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,
    intent, 0);
```

you may be getting back an existing `PendingIntent` that doesn't have your extras in it. You should use

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

instead. This will ensure that your extras are put in the `Intent`. Be aware, however, that the extras will be replaced in all users of this `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Oh great, I'll check it out later. Kinda busy right now, but it looks like solved. (=